# Flutter: BottomNavigationBar not changing the active icon color

Tags: flutter

I'm totally failing to understand why the icons in bottom navigation bar are not changing the color. The default home icon (titled as timeline) has the primary color. When other tabs are clicked, tabs change but the color doesn't. The timeline/home icon still keeps the primary color

```
 _onPageChanged(int pageIndex) {
    setState(() {
      pageIndex = pageIndex;
    });
  }

  _onTap(int pageIndex) {
    _pageController.jumpToPage(pageIndex);

  }

  Scaffold buildAuthScreen() {
    return Scaffold(
      body: PageView(
        children: <Widget>[
          Timeline(),
          ActivityFeed(),
          Upload(),
          Search(),
          Profile(),
        ],
        controller: _pageController,
        onPageChanged: _onPageChanged,
        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        currentIndex: pageIndex,
        onTap: _onTap,

        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        showUnselectedLabels: false,
        showSelectedLabels: false,
        selectedItemColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
       // unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey,
        elevation: 4.0,
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(

            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            title: Text('timeline'),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.notifications_active),
            title: Text('notifications'),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.photo_camera, size: 35.0),
            title: Text('camera'),
            ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.search),
            title: Text('search'),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.supervised_user_circle,
            ),
            title: Text('user'),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
body: TabBarView(
            children: <Widget>[
              FirstTab(),
              CustomersPage(),
              ItemsPage(),
              MorePage()
            ],
            // if you want yo disable swiping in tab the use below code
            physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            controller: tabController,
          ),
          bottomNavigationBar: SizedBox(
            height: 70,
           child: Container(
             decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  gradient: LinearGradient(begin: Alignment.topCenter, colors: [
                Color(0xFF832685),
                Color(0xFFC81379),
                //Color(0xFFFAF2FB)
              ])),
            //color: Color(0xFF832685),
            //textStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 10),
            child: TabBar(
              onTap: (index) {
                if (index == 0) {
                  setState(() {
                    this.appBarTitle = new Text('Invoices');
                    //title = "Invoices";
                  });
                } else if (index == 1) {
                  setState(() {
                    this.appBarTitle = new Text('Customers');
                    //title = "Customers";
                  });
                } else if (index == 2) {
                  setState(() {
                    this.appBarTitle = new Text('Items');
                    //title = "Items";
                  });
                } else if (index == 3) {
                  setState(() {
                    //this.appBarTitle = new Text('More');
                    title = "More";
                  });
                }
              },
              unselectedLabelColor: Colors.grey,
              indicator: UnderlineTabIndicator(
                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Color(0xFF832685), width: 0.0),
                //insets: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(50.0, 0.0, 50.0, 40.0),
              ),
              indicatorColor: Color(0xFF832685),
              labelColor: Colors.white,
              labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 11),
              tabs: <Widget>[
                Tab(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.assessment, size: 28,),
                  text: "Invoice",
                ),
                Tab(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.person_outline, size: 28,),
                  text: "Customers",
                ),
                Tab(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.format_list_bulleted, size: 28,),
                  text: "Items",
                ),
                Tab(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.more, size: 28,),
                  text: "More",
                ),
              ],
              controller: tabController,
            ),
          ),
          )
        ));
  }
```

Comment: not working on my side. I tried unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey as unselectedLabelColor isn't a property. Additionally, I need to set the showUnselectedLabels and showSelectedLabels to false as I don't want the text just the icons

Comment: thank you but your way would need many changes to my code. I removed the PageView and simply kept my tabs in a separate list. It worked finally.

Answer (score 0):

There are

```
Color selectedItemColor, 
Color unselectedItemColor
```

and

```
selectedIconTheme
unselectedIconTheme
```

props on BottomNavigationBar class, try to play with them